# How to solve this complex number question?

Tags: complex-numbers

> $i=\sqrt{-1}$ and $a,b$ and $c$ are positive integers and $$c = (a+ib)^3-191i$$ 
>    is given. Find $c$.

I expanded the equation that is given and wrote that

$$
c = a^3+3ia^2b-3ab^2-ib^3-191i \\
$$

Since $c$ is a positive integer

$$
\begin{align}
i(3a^2b-b^3) = 191i \\
3a^2b-b^3 = 191
\end{align}
$$

should be written. And we write $c$ as

$$
c = a^3-3ab^2
$$

After that i can't conclude anything. Hints and solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: since $c$ is a positive integer the imaginary part must be zero this means $$3a^2b-b^3-191=0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already wrote

$$3a^2b-b^3 = 191$$
$$a^3-3ab^2= c$$

We can factor the equations

$$b(3a^2-b^2)=191$$
$$a(a^2-3b^2)=c$$

From the first equation, $191$ is prime thus $b$ is either $191$ or $1$, so you get two sets of two equations.

When $b=1$, I get $a=8$ and $c=488$.

When $b=191$, $a$ is not an integer and we have no solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Since 191 is a prime number and $b$ is common on the left so...